# Diferença entre Console.Write() e Console.WriteLine()?

Tags: c#

Qual a diferença entre `Console.Write()` e `Console.WriteLine()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Console.Write()` escreve continuamente na mesma linha e `Console.WriteLine()` faz as quebras de linhas no código.

Comment: @MatheusW honestamente eu considero a resposta correcta!

Comment: Ola Matheus, se tiver duvidas na parte de lógica de programação e comandos básicos em c# eu posso te mandar o link de um pdf que me ajudou no começo da faculdade de jogos! :)

Comment: @IsabellaHerman manda aí mesmo que ele não tenha dúvidas. Eu gostei

Comment: @MatheusW por favor evite ser desagradável no QA ou acabará banido.

Comment: Diego aqui está o link, é realmente do básico desde comparações com Portugol até com teoria de Arrays, espero que seja útil, abraços. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByvhxYLji0poZ1JMeWFtRzJMRlU?usp=sharing

Comment: @IsabellaHerman obrigado. Eu estou fazendo curso de Unity e estou pegando qualquer artigo que ajude! Obrigado. Você manja muito...!

Answer (score 8):

```
Console.Write() //Escreve o texto na mesma linha por exemplo:

Console.Write("Olá ");
Console.Write("Mundo");
```

> Olá Mundo

```
Console.WriteLine() //Escreve o texto e logo a seguir quebra para a linha seguinte por exemplo:

Console.WriteLine("Olá ");
Console.WriteLine("Mundo");
```

> Olá 
>   Mundo

[Método Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdf6yhx5(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Método Console.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9xdyw6yk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: otima explicação amigo, obrigado

Comment: de nada, disponha :)

Answer (score 7):

**`Console.Write`** escreve um ou mais valores no *output*.

**`Console.WriteLine`** sempre adiciona um carácter de quebra de linha após escrever algo no *output*. Isso faz com que qualquer coisa que seja escrita posteriormente fique na linha abaixo.

Comment: sua resposta foi boa porem estou começando e não entendo de forma tao dificil rsrs mas obrigado amigo

Comment: @MatheusW Não entendi. Você precisa de mais detalhes?